# accessing data through props with known key names react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Just starting off learning React JS, and I've hit a bit of a brick wall.

I currently have two components (probably the wrong way to do this).

- LootBox

  - LootTable

LootBox calls to a json file via ajax, and LootTable needs to access this data.

Here's my current code.

```
var LootBox = React.createClass({
                loadLootFromServer: function() {
                    $.ajax({
                      url: this.props.url,
                      dataType: 'json',
                      cache: false,
                      success: function(data) {
                        this.setState({
                            data: data
                        });
                      }.bind(this),
                      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
                      }.bind(this)
                    });
                },
                getInitialState: function() {
                    return {data: []};
                },
                componentDidMount: function() {
                    this.loadLootFromServer();
                },
                render: function () {
                    return (
                        <LootTable data={this.state.data} />
                    )
                } 
            });
```

LootTable

```
var LootTable = React.createClass({

                render: function () {
                    return (
                        <div className="table-responsive">
                            <table className="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Head <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                    <th>Neck <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{this.props.data.head.id}</td>
                                    <td>{this.props.data.neck.id}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Shoulder <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                    <th>Chest <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Waist <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                    <th>Legs <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Feet <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                    <th>Wrist <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Gloves <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                    <th>Back <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Ring 1 <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                    <th>Ring 2 <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Trinket 1 <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                    <th>Trinket 2 <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Main Hand <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                    <th>Off Hand <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list pull-right"></span></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            });
```

Render

```
React.render(
                <LootBox url="http://127.0.0.1:3001/loot.json" />,
                document.getElementById('content')
            );
```

JSON

```
[
    {
      "main_hand": {
        "id": 113937,
        "bonus": "449"
      },
      "off_hand": {
        "id": 113960,
        "bonus": "449"
      },
      "head": {
        "id": 119321,
        "bonus": "449"
      },
      "neck": {
        "id": 113890,
        "bonus": "449"
      },
      "shoulders": {
        "id": 119322,
        "bonus": "449"
      },
      "back": {
        "id": 113878,
        "bonus": "449"
      },
      "chest": {
        "id": null,
        "bonus": "None"
      },
      "wrist": {
        "id": 113935,
        "bonus": "449"
      },
      "hands": {
        "id": 119319,
        "bonus": "449"
      },
      "waist": {
        "id": 113964,
        "bonus": "449"
      },
      "legs": {
        "id": 119320,
        "bonus": "449"
      },
      "feet": {
        "id": 113895,
        "bonus": "449"
      },
      "finger1": {
        "id": 113901,
        "bonus": "449"
      },
      "finger2": {
        "id": null,
        "bonus": "None"
      },
      "trinket1": {
        "id": 113889,
        "bonus": "449"
      },
      "trinket2": {
        "id": 113986,
        "bonus": "449"
      }
    }
]
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, because when attempting to access the props on the LootBox (e.g. this.props.data.head.id) I get a `TypeError:  undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.data.head.id')`.

Anyone any theories?

**EDIT**: after adding a console.log to the success function I'm returned with this.

```
[Log] [ (loot, line 10)
Object
back: Object
bonus: "449"
id: 113878
__proto__: Object
chest: Object
feet: Object
finger1: Object
finger2: Object
hands: Object
head: Object
legs: Object
main_hand: Object
neck: Object
off_hand: Object
shoulders: Object
trinket1: Object
trinket2: Object
waist: Object
wrist: Object
__proto__: Object
]
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting data back from the ajax call?

Comment: Hey @jordaniac89, I've checked the api call via a console log, and it's returning as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this TypeError is because your initial state for `data` on the LootBox component is an empty array.  This gets passed down to LootTable on the initial render.  This means that `this.props.data` on LootTable's initial render is an empty array, and its trying to access the `head` key on an empty array and fails to do so, resulting in the TypeError.

A possible solution is to check for an empty array before trying to access its keys.  Something like this:

```
var LootTable = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
    var headID = this.props.data.head.id == null ? "Default value" : this.props.data.head.id;
    var neckID = this.props.data.neck.is == null ? "Default value" : this.props.data.neck.id;
        return (
            <snip>
        )
    }
});
```

Then you'd simply use the created variables instead of the props in your JSX.

Comment: How would I access the data only when it's loaded, as that's the data that I want.

Comment: Or, your LootBox render could be if(this.props.data) return <LootTable> else return <div>Loading</div>

Comment: @Crob i added the snippet you suggested, and even with polling, it stays as loading.

Comment: `if(this.props.data)` will return true if `this.props.data` is an empty array.  Set the initial state for data to null in LootBox and this would work.

Answer (score -1):

Is the ajax call returning an array like you posted?

If so, you would need to do `this.props.data[0].head.id`

Answer (score -1):

Your initial render (before `componentDidMount`) isn't going to have any data, so your `LootTable` component is going to be working against an empty array, which won't work.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on this please?